# Access 2010 query to Delete where exists not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

I have to join two tables and delete from one table rows that do not exists in the second table. I am trying the query below. I should only delete 7 records but it deletes the entire PERSONS table.

```
DELETE PERSONS.*
FROM PERSONS
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT PERSONS.[IR NUMBER],
      PERSONS.[Last Name],
      PERSONS.[First Name],
      PERSONS.DOB,
      PERSONS.[Name Type]
    FROM 1 tblPERSON
    RIGHT JOIN PERSONS
      ON (
             iif(isnull([1tblPERSON].DOB) = true, "01/01/9999", [1tblPERSON].DOB) = 
             iif(isnull(PERSONS.DOB) = true, "01/01/9999", PERSONS.DOB)
         )
        AND ([1tblPERSON].FIRSTNAME = PERSONS.[First Name])
        AND ([1tblPERSON].LASTNAME = PERSONS.[Last Name])
        AND ([1tblPERSON].NAMETYPELIT = PERSONS.[Name Type])
        AND ([1tblPERSON].INCINMBR = PERSONS.[IR Number])
    WHERE (
        (
          (PERSONS.[IR Number]) IN (
            SELECT [QryIncinmbrsForDelete] ! [INCINMBR]
            FROM [QryIncinmbrsForDelete]
            )
          )
        AND (
          (PERSONS.[Last Name]) NOT IN (
            "UNKNOWN",
            "UNK",
            "UKNOWN"
            )
          )
        AND ((IsNull([1tblPERSON].[INCINMBR])) = True)
        )
    ) = true;
```

EDIT:

In this example... 1, DOE, JOHN, 1/1/1960, Cust would be deleted

1tblPERSON:

```
INCINMBR Last Name First Name DOB      NameType 
1        DOE       JON        1/1/1960 Cust 
1        SMITH     JOHN       2/2/1965 Emp 
1        JONES     JAY        3/3/1965 Cust
```

PERSONS:

```
INCINMBR Last Name First Name DOB      NameType 
1        DOE       JON        1/1/1960 Cust 
1        SMITH     JOHN       2/2/1965 Emp 
1        JONES     JAY        3/3/1965 Cust 
1        DOE       JOHN       1/1/1960 Cust
```

Comment: Definitely more info needed on this on as suggested above. I have had a quick look at the query and you should think about whether right outer join is right for what you want as this will return all of the records from the right table (persons) even if no match is found, however the filtering afterwards in the where clause should be reducing the rows returned. A look at some of the data involved would definitely help with this.

Comment: 1tblPERSON:
INCINMBR Last Name        First Name   DOB      NameType

1        DOE              JON          1/1/1960  Cust
1        SMITH            JOHN         2/2/1965  Emp
1        JONES            JAY          3/3/1965  Cust
PERSONS:
1        DOE              JON          1/1/1960  Cust
1        SMITH            JOHN         2/2/1965  Emp
1        JONES            JAY          3/3/1965  Cust
1        DOE              JOHN         1/1/1960  Cust 

In this example... 1, DOE, JOHN, 1/1/1960, Cust would be deleted

Comment: I am not sure this will make sense because I can't get the formatting correct on this post. The data is below. 
1tblPERSON:
INCINMBR Last Name        First Name   DOB      NameType

1        DOE              JON          1/1/1960  Cust
1        SMITH            JOHN         2/2/1965  Emp
1        JONES            JAY          3/3/1965  Cust
PERSONS:
1        DOE              JON          1/1/1960  Cust
1        SMITH            JOHN         2/2/1965  Emp
1        JONES            JAY          3/3/1965  Cust
1        DOE              JOHN         1/1/1960  Cust

Comment: The query QryIncinmbrsForDelete gets the unique Incinmbrs that are in both tables. There are many more rows/incinmbrs in the PERSONS table than in the 1tblPERSON table. I only want to delete from PERSONS where the Incinmbrs are EQUAL but there is NO matching name/dob/nametype in 1tblPERSON.

Comment: I forgot to say that the Select works fine. It returns the correct number of rows to delete. It is when I add the Delete and the Where exists that it brings back all rows.

Comment: whats the unique key for the PERSONS and 1tblPERSON tables? Also, is INCINMBR unique?

Comment: The unique key is made up of Incinmbr, LastName, FirstName, DOB, NameType. There are no keys set on the tables. INCINMBR is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not telling the delete statement what to delete from PERSONS, you're telling it to delete EVERYTHING if your sub-query returns ANY results (and as I understand it, you're expecting it to return 7?)

If you can provide some more information about your keys, then I can give you a full solution.

Comment: It is basically a combination key of INCINMBR,lastname,firstname,dob, nametype. I thought about the fact that the exists may not specify which records to delete but can't figure out how to do a where equals or where in because of the combination key. I might have to create two queries - one to get the 7 rows using the select and use it in the second query to delete.

Comment: You can probably just concatenate the key fields and compare that. But to be honest, I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do. I've added the sample data from your comment to your original question - can you check and confirm I've got it right?

Comment: I will try to concatenate the fields also. I have about 4000 rows in the PERSONS table and 500 rows in the 1tblPERSON table. The data in 1tblPERSON is more up to date because it is pulled from the main data source but it also has much less data (only a couple of days worth of data that has been updated). I have to append, delete and update the PERSONS table with data in the 1tblPERSON table. For the delete, if the incinmbr exists on the PERSONS table AND the name/dob/nametype combo DOES NOT exists on PERSONS for that incinmbr, then I delete it from PERSONS.